# Can two different versions of EF Core be used by two separate projects that then reference each other?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, openiddict, ef-core-6.0, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I have a .NET solution which consists of some `.NET Standard 2.0` class libraries, a few `.NET Core 5.0` console apps, a `.NET Framework 4.8` MVC website and `.NET Framework 4.8` Web API.

We use `EF Core 3.1.x` within the solution to create our database migrations which are applied to a `MySql` database.  We also use NuGet package `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 3.2.7`

We have started to upgrade the `.NET Framework 4.8` Web API to `.NET 6` and as such have taken a dependency on `OpenIddict 4.0.0` to handle authorization token generation.

`OpenIddict 4.0.0` has a dependency on `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational >= 6.0.12` which means in the upgraded `.NET 6` API we are using `EF Core 6.0.12`. **N.B. We create a separate database to hold the OpenIddict tables in.**

We therefore have 2 `DbContext` derived classes `MyProjectContext` and `OAuthDbContext`.

`MyProjectContext` lives in `.NET Standard 2.0` class library `MyProject.Data` which references `EF Core 3.1.x`.

`OAuthDbContext` lives in the upgraded `.NET 6` API `MyApi` which directly references `EF Core 6.0.12` and `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 6.0.12`.

`MyApi` has a project reference to `MyProject.Data` as we need access to the underlying data that the API returns.

As part of the `Program.cs` class in the upgraded `.NET 6` API we are using `Autofac` dependency injection to register existing `Module`s.

One of these `Module`s is the `BaseModule` which looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Autofac base module.
/// </summary>
public class BaseModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder containerBuilder)
    {
        // Register data layer.
        // Database context.
        containerBuilder.Register<DbContext>(c => new MyProjectContext()).InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        // Register services.
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<AccountService>().As<IAccountService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        //etc...
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is, when the upgraded `.NET 6` API `MyApi` is run, I get a runtime error when the `MyProjectContext` default constructor is called from loading the `BaseModule`, saying it cannot load `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql version=6.0.2.0` (which is the version used in the upgraded `.NET 6` API `MyApi`), but the in `.NET Standard 2.0` class library `MyProject.Data` where the error is thrown uses `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql version=3.2.7.0`.

```
System.TypeLoadException
  HResult=0x80131522
  Message=Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.MySqlDbContextOptionsExtensions' from assembly 'Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql, Version=6.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2cc498582444921b'.
  Source=MyProject.Data
  StackTrace:
   at MyProject.Data.MyProjectContext.GetMySQLContextOptions(String connectionString) in C:\Users\Adrian\source\repos\myproject\myproject\MyProject.Data\MyProjectObjectContext.cs:line 60
   at MyProject.Data.MyProjectContext..ctor() in C:\Users\username\source\repos\myproject\myproject\MyProject.Data\MyProjectObjectContext.cs:line 18
   at MyProject.Framework.DIModules.BaseModule.<>c.<Load>b__0_0(IComponentContext c) in C:\Users\username\source\repos\myproject\myproject\MyProject.Framework\DIModules\BaseModule.cs:line 53
   at Autofac.RegistrationExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass41_0`1.<Register>b__0(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p)
   at Autofac.Builder.RegistrationBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass0_0`1.<ForDelegate>b__0(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p)
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.<ConfigurePipeline>b__2_0(ResolveRequestContext ctxt, Action`1 next)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.DelegateMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.DisposalTrackingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.ActivatorErrorHandlingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
```

Is it possible to use two different versions of `EF Core` in referenced projects?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that `OpenIddict` assumes you want to use `EF Core 6` if you target `net6.0`, even though it is perfectly fine to use `EF Core 3.1` with `net6.0`.

---

One way to solve this should be to just build the `OpenIddict 4.0.0` repository locally.

You should then be able to reference the built `netcoreapp3.1` assemblies from your `MyApi` project.

Your `MyApi` project would then target `net6.0`, reference the locally built `netcoreapp3.1` assemblies of `OpenIddict 4.0.0` and use `EF Core 3.1` (via package reference).

Your `MyProject.Data` project would target `netstandard2.0` and use `EF Core 3.1` (via package reference).

(Instead of using the `netcoreapp3.1` assemblies of `OpenIddict`, you could of course also just change the code of `OpenIddict` to make it reference `EF Core 3.1` when targeting `net6.0`, in which case you `MyApi` project would just reference the `net6.0` assemblies of `OpenIddict`).

---

Another way is to use multi-targeting for your `MyProject.Data` project.

You would need some preprocessor conditions around your `UseMySql()` call, because the signature changed between Pomelo 3.1 and 5.0 (a mandatory server version parameter was added).

Your `MyApi` project would target `net6.0`, `OpenIddict 4.0.0` (via package reference) and use `EF Core 6.0` (via package reference).

Your `MyProject.Data` project would target `netstandard2.0` and use `EF Core 3.1` (via package reference) *and also* target `net6.0` and use `EF Core 6.0` (via package reference).

Comment: `even though it is perfectly fine to use EF Core 3.1 with net6.0`: I personally disagree with that for two reasons: using EF Core or ASP.NET Core packages with a different TFM than the one it's designed for has never been supported, even though it happened to just work in many cases (the team has always been very clear about that: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/45149#issuecomment-1320517662). For the first time, EF Core 7 made an exception, but it's causing all sorts of issues for these reasons, so not sure they'll do that for the next version.

Comment: OpenIddict 4.0 follows the same logic by matching the packages and the TFMs: if you want to use OpenIddict with EF Core 3.1 - which is no longer supported by Microsoft BTW - you must target .NET Core 3.1. The compatibility issue here is caused by the fact the OP is referencing two different versions of Pomolo that are not binary compatible. To fix that, the easiest option is likely to target .NET Core 3.1 instead of 6.0 and use the Pomolo 3.2.7 package for everything to match and work correctly.

Comment: BTW, OpenIddict 4.0's `netstandard2.0` TFM references EF Core 2.1, which is still supported on .NET Framework thanks to 2.1's super-long LTS policy. If you're stuck on older frameworks, 2.1 is arguably a better choice than 3.1, that will no longer receive any update from Microsoft. That said, I don't think Pomolo still supports 2.1, so likely not a perfect choice either 

Comment: @KévinChalet EF Core 3.1 is fully compatible with TFM `net6.0`. ASP.NET Core 6 is not dependent at all on any version of EF Core. So using EF Core 3.1 with ASP.NET Core 6, targeting `net6.0` is perfectly fine. Whether that is also the case for other libraries like OpenIddict, is a different matter.

Comment: I agree that a third option is to target `netcoreapp3.1` in both projects and use EF Core 3.1 and a compatible OpenIddict version. But since the OP seems to want to upgrade immediately to `net6.0`, I am not mentioning it in my answer.

Comment: Not sure why you're mentioning ASP.NET Core: EF Core relies on multiple `Microsoft.Extensions` packages and using `Microsoft.Extensions` packages with a different .NET TFM has never been **officially** supported, even if it worked. But since you're mentioning ASP.NET Core, there are multiple ASP.NET Core packages that do depend on EF Core, like https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore or https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.EntityFrameworkCore. And the rule is to always match the EF Core version with the TFM.

Comment: IMHO, it seems a bit... strange to suggest building a custom version of OpenIddict as a first option to work around a binary incompatibility caused by referencing two different/incompatible versions of your Pomelo provider. OpenIddict has nothing to with this error, which would occur anyway if you directly referenced EF Core 6.0 without OpenIddict. In this case, why not suggesting building a custom version of the Pomelo provider without the breaking change causing the issue? 

Comment: EF Core providers are only binary compatible to a single major version of EF Core, since many breaking changes (at least internally) are introduced in ever major version of EF Core. This is a fundamental design decision by the EF Core team. So there is no version of any EF Core provider out there, that is simultaneously compatible with EF Core 3.1 and EF Core 6.0. When it comes to OpenIddict however, there should be no issue in just using EF Core 3.1 when targeting `net6.0`. Therefore, just compiling OpenIddict locally should be the quickest/most efficient option for the OP.

Comment: Well, nothing prevents a provider package from targeting multiple versions of EF Core (one per TFM) and using `#if` to support all EF Core versions in the same provider version: you decided to have a provider version per EF Core version, but it's a design choice, not a technical requirement. Regarding OpenIddict, it's typically used with ASP.NET Core Identity, whose EF Core integration package targets EF Core 6.0. Unless you're using OpenIddict without Identity - which is not the most common case - you'll hit the same issue when referencing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore`.

Comment: I presented two options, in the order of how fast they can be implemented. I am sure there are multiple ways to do it. These are the two that I would personally choose from (assuming I would want to use ASP.NET 6), both have their individual advantages and disadvantages (maintenance vs. long-term risk). Others might have different valid and working options as well. So far, I am the only one who made the effort to post something actionable.

Comment: `So far, I am the only one who made the effort to post something actionable`. That's good and that's why I upvoted it. But your first sentence indicating the issue is caused by OpenIddict is inaccurate and deserved a different perspective that I shared as comments under your answer. That's how StackOverflow works, no?